# creating login page using PHP for iPhone?

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, ios4

i am trying to create a login page for iPad by using Mysql through PHP, But it is not logging in even though there is no error in page, please find the code below:

```
//-(IBAction)homePage: (id)sender{

NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",loginName.text, password.text];

NSString *hostStr = @"http://localhost/iddb.php";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"Yes"]){{ 


    homepage *hvc = [[homepage alloc]initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
    hvc.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:hvc animated: YES];}

    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"success" message:@"You are authorized"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alertsuccess show];


} else {
    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fail" message:@"Invalid Access"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alertsuccess show];


}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $check = "select username, password from login where username='$username' and password='$password'";
    {
      mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die();
      mysql_select_db("dadsdb") or die (mysql_error());
    }

    $login = mysql_query($check) or die (mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($login)==1) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($login);
      echo 'yes';
      exit;
    } else {
      echo 'No';
      exit;
    }
?>
```

please can any one suggest me what went wrong

Comment: Please edit your post and add the PHP code there.

Comment: That PHP code makes my hair stand up....

Comment: I copied php code from comments into question body. I also indented it accordingly. It should be obvious that the code provided has a syntax error, because there are { and } braces where they shouldn't be.

Comment: @Janis: if i run Php it is displaying "NO"

Comment: Don't you think that you should have practice to accept the old answers with asking the new one?

Comment: Your server is outputting "yes" and your app is checking for "Yes". There might be other problems but that will definitely stop it from working.

Comment: Be careful, your PHP code is vulnerable to SQL injection! You must sanitize your username and password variables.

Comment: Don't use a `localhost` URL, it won't work once you test it on your iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **case sensitve** results!

```
'yes' != 'Yes'
```

Comment: Right there, so subtle! Good find!

Answer (score 0):

In your URL, you aren't separating your php from the paramters with a ?

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",loginName.text, password.text];
NSString *hostStr = @"http://localhost/iddb.php";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
```

This will end up with

http://localhost/iddb.phpusername=....
whereas you should have
http://localhost/iddb.php?username=....

HOWEVER...  This is one of many things that you have problems with in your code.  Please take note of the comments and the other answers people have given you - 
* you need to check your case sensitivity.
* Read up about SQL Injection
* Do NOT use root as your login on your database
* Do NOT use root without a password on your database
* Do NOT store passwords in plaintext
* Do NOT send passwords in plaintext across any connection (e.g. in your URL)

You have some VERY SERIOUS problems with your PHP code which could result in someone logging in without valid username and password, being able to access all of your data or worse.